# Limit distance of the spontaneous combustion zone

Tags: sunshine

In the movie [sunshine](/questions/tagged/sunshine), a spaceship is travelling towards the sun to put a bomb in it to allow it to shine again (hence the title). The spaceship has a massive shield/deflector at the front to protect itself against the sun.

During the whole movie we can see that **everything that goes pass that deflector is spontaneously vaporised**!

Question : in the movie's universe, is there mentionned a limit in space where spacewalking pass the deflector could be done without being immediatly wiped of existence ?

*Side note : I'm not discussing the science of approaching the sun and not be destroyed nor radiated, [according to this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LIpDpRUVrNU) it is possible for a standard spaceship or a leaded spacesuit to stay intact at a fairly short distance of the sun.*

Comment: Not in the movie's universe but [ShadowZone made a recreation of Sunshine in Kerbal Space Program](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUOB6x-na1k). Apparently this limit can occur at approx. 1 million km of the Sun's surface.